# How can I speed up this basic function which cleans up multiple ranges through all the tabs?

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets

Could you please help me improve this function with the purposes to loop all the tabs within the spreadsheet to clean up all the columns where an ArrayFormula is placed in top (because of another task before it). My Function does the job, but runs sometimes in 420.678 s (according to the Executions Dashboard). So maybe it could be improved ?

one of the runs was completed in: 420.678 s

my record was: 69.946 s

my last attempts: it did the job in 177.251 s

Thanks a lot

**CODE**

```
  // SCRIPT 4:  CleanUp for Arrayformula Columns

 function CleanArrayFormula() {

var tabs = [
    'A',
    'B',
    'C',
    'D',
    'E',
    'F',
    'G',
    'H',
    'I',
    'J',
    'K',
    'L',
    'M',
    'N'

];

var ss=SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
for (var i = 0; i < tabs.length; i++) {
    var spreadsheet=ss.getSheetByName(tabs[i]);

 spreadsheet.getRangeList(['B6:E36', 'G6:I36','T6:T36', 'Z6:Z36', 'AC6:AC36', 'AN6:AN36', 'AT6:AT36', 'AW6:AW36', 'BH6:BH36', 'BN6:BN36', 'BQ6:BQ36', 'CB6:CB36', 'CH6:CH36', 'CK6:CK36', 'CV6:CV36', 'DB6:DB36', 'DE6:DE36', 'DP6:DP36', 'DV6:DV36', 'DY6:DY36', 'EJ6:EJ36', 'EP6:EP36', 'ES6:ES36']).activate()
 .clear({contentsOnly: true, skipFilteredRows: true}); 
 }
};
```

Thanks !!

Comment: If you `arrayformulas` are in B6, C6,D6 etc why are you clearing the whole range B6:E36?  Just clear the rows that contain the formulas. Or am I understanding this correctly?

Comment: Because of a task taking place just before it (pasted values on their way), so I need to clear anything on those columns, so that the array-formula works again. Thank you (Arrayformula are in top of those columns that I'm cleaning)

Comment: @Nabnub I imagine you're referring to the Execution Transcript. with the wide range in times that you mention, the transcript should give you a good idea of what is occupying most time, and what is varying from run-to-run. Where do you believe your bottleneck exists? BTW, how long does your spreadsheet take to recalculate?